# Cannot access function within component - Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Cannot figure this one out. I have a OnInit function that gets a result from the server. with that result I expect to run a function which angular2 is complaining "this.secondsToTime is not a function"

Here is my code:

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this._authService.user;
    this._globalService.getPrintTimer().subscribe(
        suc => {
            this.secondsToTime(suc.response);
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Could not load timer");
        }
    );
}

secondsToTime(time) {
    console.log("secondsToTime");
    setTimeout(function () {
        time--;
        time = Math.round(time);
        var hours = Math.floor(time / (60 * 60));

        var divisor_for_minutes = time % (60 * 60);
        var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

        var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
        var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

        this.countDown = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: this might refer to an internal calling function scope here try to save a reference outside as var that = this before call and then use that.secondsToTime(suc.response);

Comment: Add a 'console.log(this);' in your success callback and let us know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be of the scope, when using promises or Observables the scope retrieved in the callback functions( success, error, finally, complete) is of the class where it was declared. I used to get this error while writing code in ES5, ES6 and haven't faced it from the time I started using arrow functions to declare my functions/methods since arrow functions are block scoped.

To solve the same in your case, this modification in the code should work:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this._authService.user;
    this._globalService.getPrintTimer().subscribe(
        suc => {
            this.secondsToTime(suc.response);
        }.bind(this),
        err => {
            console.log("Could not load timer");
        }.bind(this)
    );
}
```

I created a plnkr in order to replicate the error but was not able to replicate it with the code your provided since you are using arrow functions, the code in the globalService may provide some more useful information, however the same issue can be replicated if arrow functions are replaced by function() {}, modified code:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this._authService.user;
    this._globalService.getPrintTimer().subscribe(
        function(suc) {
            this.secondsToTime(suc.response);
        }.bind(this),
        function(err) {
            console.log("Could not load timer");
        }.bind(this)
    );
}
```

if we remove the bind() method, we will get the error, this.secondsToTime is not defined.
Here is link to plnkr for the same: https://plnkr.co/edit/vMbkdG4F5CbQxfyXGIHQ?p=preview.

You can try removing the bind function in the plnkr and check error in the terminal.